# Compare frequencies in HUGE number of categories

Tags: r, contingency-tables, bioinformatics, many-categories

I have 2 samples, each with many (e.g. 100'000) different categories (colors in urn model), and counts for each category (number of balls of each color -  many with few counts, and few with higher counts - but cannot leave outh the low-count categories, since these low-count categories alltogether hold most of counts, even  though I am interested mainly in the "dominant" categories. I.e. I do not care about categories with relatively low counts in group A and even lower in group B).

See example data table below. Think of a HUGE urn, with balls of millions of colors, and plenty of balls of each color. Two random samples (, and I want to know if they could be from the same basic population (H0), or should be from 2 different urns (H1).

Total counts differs in between samples, by factor about 10, resulting in most categories WITH counts in sample A (i.e. 1-100'000 in example), and many categories in group B appear "empty" in group B (1,2,4,5,6...)(i.e. sampling bias, which I want to overcame). It is for technical reasons not possible to increaese total counts in the smaller sample.

=> first-impression differences may be because of *much* lower sample sizes in the second group.

I'd prefer an implementation in R if possible, and would be happy for hints to helpful functions/packages/examples.

**Goal:**

a) do the groups differ overall, i.e. reject that they stem from the same basic population?

b) most important: which individual categories have significantly different counts?

**ad a)** I was first thinking of sth. like Chi-square test, but there are quite some categories with very few counts, and I wonder if this is the test of choice (and I am afraid that > 100'000 categories will break the test or the implementation).

**ad b)** unsure how to address, but was thinking of taking subsamples from the bigger sample, each of the size of the smaller group, and see what the mean and confidence intervals are, and then judge if the counts in the smaller sample are within these limits. Unsure how to deal with multipel testing in this context (but I am interested only in the dominant categories)

It is about cells in a biological sample, the cells have genetic variants ("colors") of a highly variable region, not classical microarray data. Several thousand cells = variants can co-exist in tissue samples. Anyway, using applicable packgages primarily used for gene expression analysis would also be fine if accessible and not relying on gene names.

I was searching for answers on this or similar problems on CV and Google for some hours, but could not find an answer for this extreme problem. Every help is appreciated to solve the 2 goals.

**Example of data:**
[image: example data table]

Comment: What is the total number of counts?

Comment: For a) you could use chi-square, but use simulation to study the null distribution. Or even bootstrapping. For b) I would start with correspondence analysis, maybe bootstrap that. Or do individual binomial tests (null: equal p's), getting the p-value for each, and then base a test on empirical null. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109694/using-empirical-null-distribution-to-adjust-odds-ratios) has references.

Comment: I always find a bit of background helps with a sense check here. Could you provide any more information about what the groups are, an idea of the variables etc?

Comment: Please clarify:  you cannot leave out the low-count categories, even though you are interested only in the "dominant" categories.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen total number of counts is about 550'000. Added example data to clarify.

Comment: Can you post (a link to) (part of, or mockup of) your data?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks - would a csv file help? Data is at university, will send a link when I get back.

Comment: @rolando2 The lower part of the table consist of "colors" with low frequency, maybe only few balls in the one or other sample. Taken together they account for a relevant proportion of balls, but I a minterested in colors with many balls in at least on sample.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Did you mean "Large-Scale Simultaneous Hypothesis Testing:
The Choice of a Null Hypothesis" by Efron 2004 (Link is broken)?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that's the paper. And a csv will do!